# Как вывести все изображения, которые присутсвуют в блоке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить головоломку.
Нужно вывести все изображения, который присутствуют в блоке, в отдельное место.
При добавлении этапа готовки блюда, мы добавляем шаговую инструкцию приготовления, в каждом шаге присутствует своя картинка готовки. В полной новости шаги также разбиты по блокам. Нужно с этого блока вывести все картинки отдельно.
Хочу вывести их в Карусель.
Друзья, если кто-то знает как это реализовать, помогите пожалуйста!

В этом контейнере уже выводятся картинки с описанием приготовления в полной новости.

```
<div class="recept_shagi">
<ol>
  <li>
    <img src="https://cdn.tveda.ru/thumbs/f4c/f4c2e449fc5506af781914d78c09d692/5c8fedc6bccd8a543b750a175d1dd17f.jpg">
    Шаг первый
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://cdn.tveda.ru/thumbs/f4c/f4c2e449fc5506af781914d78c09d692/5c8fedc6bccd8a543b750a175d1dd17f.jpg">
    Шаг второй
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://cdn.tveda.ru/thumbs/f4c/f4c2e449fc5506af781914d78c09d692/5c8fedc6bccd8a543b750a175d1dd17f.jpg">
    Шаг третий
  </li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Есть карусель куда нужно вывести все картинки из блока class="recept_shagi" в id="caruselka". Чтобы каждая картинка была завернута div class="item".

Ниже сама карусель и пример, как должны выводится картинки.

```js
//Карусель новостей
$('.item>img').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).prop('src');
  $('#big_img').html('<img src="' + src + '">');
});
```

```css
#big_img img {
 width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
#caruselka .item {
  float:left;
  margin: 5px;
}
#caruselka .item img {
 width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big_img" class="poster"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/23/19/57/asparagus-2169305_1280.jpg"></div>

 <div id="caruselka">
   <div class="item">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/23/19/57/asparagus-2169305_1280.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/06/09/06/07/barbecue-123668_1280.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/19/20/59/hamburger-494706_1280.jpg">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Буду Вам благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.recept_shagi img');
let carusel = document.getElementById('caruselka');

[...imgs].forEach((img) => {
    let item = document.createElement('div');
    item.classList.add('item');
    let image = img.cloneNode(false);
    item.appendChild(image);
    carusel.appendChild(item);
});
```

Что-то вроде этого, но не факт.

Comment: Не работает, пустой блок без картинок.

Comment: Вроде все правильно, сделал клонирование элементов, теперь может?

Comment: В песочнице попробовал, все работает.

Comment: Если не клонировать img, то они исчезают в Шагах и переходят в карусель. Если клонировать, то остаются и там и здесь.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, все работает!